# Can I use the data studio API to pull data from a report?

Tags: looker-studio

Is there a way to pull the data from a report in Google Data Studio through the API? One of my clients wants to generate a report in data studio and then export it to Google Sheets so he can run additional functions. I can't seem to find any documentation that talks about how to do that. Alternatively, is it easier to skip the report, query the data sources directly, and do the uploading that way?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can only get the info about reports, but not report data.

The API is available here: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api/reference

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there is no API to pull data from a Data Studio report.